# How does WP decide how to display a page

Tags: posts, comments, post-meta, comment-meta

I am new to WP. I tried reading up as much as I possibly can online, and via browsing through the files. As far as I can tell, no physical pages/links are stored on the disk, so when a page is created, the data is stored in the wp_posts table, and the post metadata is in the wp_postmeta table. My questions are:

1. I am assuming that nothing is stored to disk, with the exception of uploads that go into the wp-contents/uploads directory. Is this correct?
2. Are there any other tables involved in the posts? as in, if I delete the post from the wp_posts and all relevant data from the wp_postmeta, does that get rid of the post?
3. How does WP know if this is a page or a post? which table is that info stored in?
4. Are the wp_comments and wp_commentmeta tables the only tables involved in comments. As in, if I write as script to delete a comment from this table, along with its metadata, will that completely eliminate the post?

Comment: There are a lot of questions here, answering correctly and comprehensively will take a large amount of time and effort, equivalent to a small novel. Increase your chances of good answers by breaking your question up and asking multiple questions on the site. Link between them for greater context. How WordPress gets from a URL to a post and template to load itself is an in depth topic even without the 4 bullet points you added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has a [predefined folder structure](http://www.howtospoter.com/web-20/wordpress/wordpress-guide-dissection-of-file-structure) and runs on a [database](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/2/2a/WP3.9.4-ERD.png) with a clearly defined structure. The [description of the tables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) and the relationship between them is defined.

1. You can store on the disk the plugins as well as the content that goes into /uploads, like you've mentioned.
2. Yes, it should get rid of the post.
3. in `wp_pages` table in the field `post_type`. You might find the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png) also useful, with this you can customize posts, pages, categories etc
4. Yes, it should get rid of the comments